# Solution to run a .NET component on regular intervals in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-services, scheduling

I need to write some .NET code that runs on a regular interval to check for "unprocessed" items in a table in the database, processes them, and then writes back to the database that they are processed.  We'll probably set it up to run every minute.

How can I set up in the component in a Windows Server environment so that the code executes on a periodic basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) in your windows service.

You can have such a code (from MSDN) in your windows service OnStart event :

```
// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

// Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
timer.Interval = 2000;
timer.Enabled = true;

...........

// Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ......
}
```

If the interval is not frequent for example if it runs daily also consider using [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm). It can run your application for the given interval (note if that interval is **not** so frequent).

Answer (score 3):

Create a scheduled task through the Windows Task Scheduler.  The scheduled task would then run your compiled .NET EXE (I'm assuming it's an EXE) on a periodic basis.  If you need it to run shorter than a minute, I think you then need to move to a windows service.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Scheduled Tasks (start-programs-accessories-system tools)... SSIS Job Scheduling... 3rd Party Job Software (Activebatch, etc)...

Answer (score 1):

You can either set it up as a service with a timer which goes off whenever you want (for this frequency, probably your best option) or you can set up a scheduled task in Windows Scheduler.

If you're going with the windows service route, your Start() method will look something like:

```
Timer tmr = new Timer(60000, true) //this could be wrong: set it for one minute and turn on auto-reset.

tmr.Start();
```

Then you'll have an event handler to handle the Timer's event (can't remember the name right now: Tick, maybe?) which will call your actual code.

If your code takes longer than a minute to complete, you might set auto-restart to `false` and then re-enable your timer when the processing protion hands control back to the service.